# What does the Auth0 error message "Suspicious request requires verification" mean?

Tags: auth0

I'm trying to implement a password-based login for a Vue app. Everything seems to work fine, but when I try this:

```
this.auth0.client.login(
      {
        realm: 'Username-Password-Authentication',
        username: 'user@whatever.com',
        password: 'totallyValidpassw0rd',
        audience: 'https://my-site.eu.auth0.com/userinfo',
        scope: 'read:order write:order'
      },
      (err, authResult) => {
         console.log(err);
      });
```

the result is a cryptic `Suspicious request requires verification` error message. What exactly is suspicious, and what should be verified?

Answer (score 1):

It's supposed to mean that the captcha hasn't been solved. As I found, password based login (Password Grant or Resource Owner Password flow) can't be used together with the Bot detection feature, which is a fancy name for a captcha. Turning off Bot detection solves the problem.

Of course now a third party captcha (like Google reCaptcha) will have to be added to the login form.